# Crash when accessing NSNumber from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

I am facing a strange crash where an instance of `NSNumber` seems to be deallocated although it persists in array. I have created a system to download multiple files from remote server and have a block to indicate progress (an average progress really). And the computation of the progress produces a crash. The crash is not consistent and happens "usually" at can occur at any point. `[_NSProgressFractionTuple floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17042ab80` leads me to believe the `NSNumber` is somehow deallocated and I fail to see how this is possible.

To give the full method code:

```
- (void)downloadFilesFromURLs:(NSArray<NSString *> *)urlPaths withProgress:(void (^)(float progress))progressBlock completion:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionBlock {
    NSMutableArray *toLoad = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSString *path in urlPaths) {
        if([self fileForURL:path] == nil) {
            [toLoad addObject:path];
        }
    }

    NSInteger itemsToLoad = toLoad.count;

    if(itemsToLoad <= 0) {
        if(completionBlock) {
            completionBlock(nil);
        }
        return;
    }



    // Set progresses to zero
    __block NSMutableArray *progresses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0; i<itemsToLoad; i++) [progresses addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:.0f]];

    __block NSInteger requestsOut = itemsToLoad;
    __block NSError *latestError = nil;
    for(int i=0; i<itemsToLoad; i++) {
        NSInteger index = i;
        [self downloadFileFromURL:toLoad[index] named:nil withProgress:^(float progress) {
            progresses[index] = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:progress];
            if(progressBlock) {
                float overallProgress = .0f;
                for(NSNumber *number in [progresses copy]) {
                    overallProgress += number.floatValue;
                }
                progressBlock(overallProgress/itemsToLoad);
            }
        } completion:^(NSString *filePath, NSError *error) {
            if(error) latestError = error;
            requestsOut -= 1;
            if(requestsOut <= 0) {
                if(completionBlock) {
                    completionBlock(latestError);
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

**Code explanation:**

So this method accepts an array of URLs. It then checks if some of the files were already downloaded and creates a new array which only contains URLs that need to be downloaded. If all files exist or no URLs are provided then the completion is called and the operation breaks.

Next I create a mutable array and fill it with `NSNumber` instances all having a zero value. I remember how many requests will be made and I create a placeholder for an error. I iterate through all the URLs and initialize requests where each will report a progress and completion and both of these are on a main thread.

So in progress block I access the array of progresses to assign the new values through indexing. I then compute an average progress and report overall progress to an input block.

The request completion decreases the number of requests counter and when that one falls to zero the input completion is called.

**The situation:**

It all works as expected, the whole procedure is correct. The given values are all valid and all the files are there on the server and are accessible. When the app does not crash it all works as it should.

But when it crashes it crashes in

```
                for(NSNumber *number in [progresses copy]) {
                    overallProgress += number.floatValue;
                }
```

and the crash is random but in any case the `number.floatValue` seems to be accessing a memory that it shouldn't.

I now have a solution where I replaced the `progresses` array with pure C pointer `float *progresses = malloc(sizeof(float)*itemsToLoad);` which is freed on completion. It seems to work but still, what am I missing here? What could be the cause of array with `NSNumbers` not working here?

**Some additional info:**

- Memory is OK, this is writing directly into files and even if it didn't the overall file size is relatively small
- Disk space is OK
- I was using `@(progress)` syntax but changed it to explicit allocation in hopes of removing the issue
- `progresses` does not need `__block`, I added it just in case
- Completion does not get called before all the progresses get called and even if it did I see no reason to crash the app

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't explicitly answer your question but you should checkout an awesome foundation class that is design to track this exact kind of progress - https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/progress.

Comment: @JonRose Thank you for this one but in my case I have no reason to use a higher level of API since all the code is in one place. It would just be a different for loop. I did manage to fix the issue with allocating an array of floats as well. So I am generally interested in how could this possibly crash or rather how could the NSNumber instance possibly be deallocated in this chunk of code.

Comment: is the `progresses` array accessed anywhere else that we don't see?  could the instance that is calling this have been dealloc when the download is taking place?

Comment: @JonRose The array is created within the method and is used only inside this method. I posted all the code there is. Still this is something that has crossed my mind but the only way I see this could happen if there was a completely different bug in another part of the project. But since there were no other strange crashes and no other part of the project crashed I have abandoned this idea. Still if it is then it will be a pain to find. One of such I had a long time ago was MyStruct *myStruct = malloc(sizof(myStruct)). The autocomplete used lowercase and access to pointer was overflowing...

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableArray` is not thread safe.  So even though there is no explicit memory management issue, if `NSMutableArray` is accessed at the same time by two different thread bad things can happen.  I believe that dispatching the `withProgress` block in a serial queue would solve the issue.